# Linear combination of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V = \operatorname{span}\left\{[2,0,4,0]^T,[0,1,0,1]^T,[0,0,-1,-1]^T\right\}$.
>
> Show that each of the below vectors belong to $V$ by writing it as a linear combination of the given basis of $V$:
>
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 2\\1\\4\\1
> \end
> {bmatrix},
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\1\\1\\0
> \end
> {bmatrix},
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 6\\-2\\7\\-7
> \end{bmatrix}

### My thoughts:

Is this done by finding $a$, $b$, and $c$, where

\begin{bmatrix}
2\\0\\4\\0
\end
{bmatrix} =
a\begin{bmatrix}
2\\1\\4\\1
\end
{bmatrix}+
b\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1\\1\\0
\end
{bmatrix}+
c\begin{bmatrix}
6\\-2\\7\\-7
\end{bmatrix}

and repeating for the other two vectors in $V$?

Comment: Nop: the $\;a,b,c\;$ must multiply each of the vectors generating the span and then this must be equalled to each of the other three vectors given.

Comment: @Timbuc so the vectors are in the opposite places of what I originally thought?

Comment: Seems so to me.

Answer (score 1):

Close.
$$
U = \mbox{span} \{  u_1, u_2, u_3 \} 
$$
Then
$$
v \in U \iff v = c_1 u_1 + c_2 u_2 + c_3 u_3
$$
for some $c_1, c_2, c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$.

You can write it as matrix problem
$$
(u_1, u_2, u_3) (c_1, c_2, c_3)^T = (v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)^T
$$
and try Gauss elimination
$$
(u_1, u_2, u_3 \,|\, v) -> (E \,|\, c)
$$

Frist:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2 & 0 & 0  & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 0  & 1 \\
4 & 0 & -1 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\to
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Second:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2 & 0 & 0  & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0  & 1 \\
4 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\to
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Third:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2 & 0 & 0  & 6 \\
0 & 1 & 0  & -2 \\
4 & 0 & -1 & 7\\
0 & 1 & -1 & -7
\end{array}
\right)
\to
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
You can read the $c_i$ from the first three components of the last column.

Answer (score 0):

You can save quite some time doing the restricted coefficients matrix's reduction and then taking any vector, doing the same operations on it and checking whether you get a congruent solution:

$$\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
4&0&\!\!-1\\
0&1&\!\!-1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-2R_1\;,\;\;R_4-R_2}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&\!\!-1\\
0&0&\!\!-1\end{pmatrix} (**)$$

Now take the first vector and do the same operations as above:

$$\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\4\\1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-2R_1\,,\,\,R_4-R_2}\rightarrow=\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}(*)$$

If you now put (**) to the left of (*),  you get

$$-c=0\;,\;\;b=1\;,\;\;a=1$$

and we certainly get that

$$1\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\4\\0\end{pmatrix}+1\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\4\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Do the same with the other two vectors you're asked about.